# Подтянуть значение (сумму значений), соответствующее двум критериям, из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: excel

Бухгалтер вносит данные о расходах нескольких торговых точек на листе "Расходы магазинов" с указанием категории расхода, даты, наименования торговой точки и суммы расхода. Категорий расходов около 20. За один день в таблицу может быть добавлено несколько строк с указанием одной торговой точки, но с разными категориями расходов.

Параллельно, на странице "Касса", ведётся другая таблица. Необходимо, чтобы сумма расходов определенной торговой точки за определенный день переносилась автоматически в таблицу на странице "Касса".

На скриншоте показал то, что описал выше.

[image: Пример]

Comment: [СУММЕСЛИМН()](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сводные таблицы. Добавите дату, магазин в "Названия столбцов" и сумму в "значения".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отличный инструмент для аналитика, но не для бухгалтера - она же захочет напротив каждой строки дописать сведения о платеже и ещё кучу всякого... Понаписывает, а после обновления Сводной - р-р-раз! - и все её записи съехали на другие строки

Comment: Значения из сводной таблице по `ВПР()` подтягивайте в нужную таблицу для бухгалтера.

Comment: Тогда уж не ВПР(), а [ПОЛУЧИТЬ.ДАННЫЕ.СВОДНОЙ.ТАБЛИЦЫ()](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/8/229/)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `СУММЕСЛИ()`

Функция СУММЕСЛИ используется, если необходимо просуммировать значения диапазон, соответствующие указанному критерию.

При необходимости условия можно применить к одному диапазону, а просуммировать соответствующие значения из другого диапазона. Например, формула `=СУММЕСЛИ(B2:B5; "Иван"; C2:C5)` суммирует только те значения из диапазона C2:C5, для которых соответствующие значения из диапазона B2:B5 равны "Иван".

В вашем случае `=СУММЕСЛИ(B:B;$B4;D:D)` должно хватить